# PDF to IMG to PDF all done in memory

Tags: python, pdf, in-memory

In order to remove sensitive content from a PDF, I am converting it to image and back to PDF again.

I am able to do this while saving the jpeg image, however I would eventually like to adapt my code so that the file is in memory the whole time. PDF in memory -> JPEG in memory -> PDF in memory. I'm having trouble with the intermediary step.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
import img2pdf

images = convert_from_path('testing.pdf', fmt='jpeg')
image = images[0]

# opening from filename
with open("output/output.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(image.tobytes()))
```

On the last line, I am getting the error:

`ImageOpenError: cannot read input image (not jpeg2000). PIL: error reading image: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1040cc8f0>`

I'm not sure how to be converting this image to the string that `img2pdf` is looking for.

Comment: img2pdf.convert method accepts list file names, so you have to store all your converted images to some directory and give those image paths as input to convert method. Then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The pdf2image module will extract the images as Pillow images.  And according the Pillow [tobytes() documention](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes): "This method returns the raw image data from the internal storage."  Which is some bitmap representation.

To get your code working use BytesIO module like so:

```
# opening from filename
import io
with open("output/output.pdf","wb") as f, io.BytesIO() as output:
    image.save(output, format='jpg')
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(output.getvalue()))
```

Comment: This was helpful. In the case of cv2 images, I was able to write the buffer using `_, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", image)` and then create the BytesIO buffer using `buffers.append(io.BytesIO(buffer))`. I can then create a multi-page PDF with `img2pdf.convert(buffers)`.